# How to access URL parameters in bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

I'm trying to capture a URL parameter in my bootstrap file but after several attempts I'm not able to do it.

I've tried this but it does not work:

```
protected function _initGetLang() {
  $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $lang= $frontController->getParam('lang');
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Thks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't be able to access the request params from the bootstrap because it hasn't yet gone through the dispatch/routing process. I think you'd be better served by using a [Controller Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html), performing actions based on the URL is what they do best. Or if you absolutely have to do it in the bootstrap, `getRequestUri()` or `$_GET` is available, or you could write a quick script to parse the url yourself.

**Edit:**

I've done some silly stuff like this in the past before I figured out how plugins work:

```
/**
 * Grab the module name without a request instance
 *
 * @return string  The module name
 */
public static function getModuleName()
{
    $uri = ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/");
    $module = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, "/"));
    return $module;
}
```

This would at least give you a module name that you could `switch` on in the bootstrap. You should be able to do anything you need with the plugins done correctly though.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, I tried the Plugin approach before but it didn't do what I wanted, nevertheless I'll read the article that 'lonut G. Stan' to check if I did something wrong, If that doesn't work, I'll do the $_GET thing that 'Typeoneerror' suggest.